# Gradle is failing on syncing my project in the new Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.0

I have just upgraded (i.e., installed a full new version) my Android Studio from 1.5 to 2.0. The upgrade seemed to go smoothly, but I am having trouble with my project when I open it, when Gradle is syncing my project.

After Gradle sync runs for a couple of minutes I get this error:

```
Failed to sync Gradle project MyProject
    Unknown host 'jcenter.bintray.com'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.
    Error:  Enable Gradle "offline mode' and sync project
            Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle
```

So, I click on the link that says:

```
Enable Gradle "offline mode' and sync project
```

Then Gradle spins for a second or two, and I now have this message:

```
Failed to sync Gradle project MyProject
    Error: No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0 available for offline mode.
           Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

So, I click on this link:

```
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

And I am back to my first error again.

The machine I am working on is 100% off line. It does not have, nor will it ever have any kind of network connection whatsoever. I figure I need to disable some kind of check that requires the internet, but I am not sure what. Is this fixable, or do I have to downgrade back to Android Studio 1.5?

**UPDATE**

I am also getting this error message:

```
Gradle sync failed: Unknown host 'services.gradle.org'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.
```

Comment: You didn't get prompt to update gradle too? `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'`

Comment: Not that I saw. Where would I look for this message?

Comment: I just updated myself except my box isn't disconnected from the internet.  the `build.gradle` on the project-level, not the app-level, contains the gradle version.  perhaps installing a full version instead of an update will resolve the gradle / offline issue?

Comment: I did install the full version. ~1.2Gb download off of Google's Android developer site.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ok, I fixed my issue so I wanted to post how I did it in case somebody else runs into this situation.

I was googling around and [found a statement](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-use-Android-Studio-offline) regarding working offline with Android Studio that read:

> You can, however you won't be able to use any Gradle dependency. Gradle search into the repositories for dependencies using internet, so if you're completely unable to work online. Try not to include anything in the Gradle files, if you do, you'll have to sync it and it'll fail. Bascially just don't touch Gradle files and you'll be good to go.

So, I looked at my gradle files, specifically the build.gradle for the Project (not for the Module). Once there, I noticed a line:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
}
```

So, I replaced `1.3.0` with `2.0.0` and the project built just fine.

I hope this helps somebody else in the future. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

I got same problem when I downloaded "BackboneExampleApp" source code from guithub [Click Here For Code](https://github.com/ResearchStack/BackboneExampleApp). I have done following process by watching settings of my old projects and found these errors. I resolved both errors, run my app and got errors to upgrade project and finally when I updated then no more problems exist. Just see pictures for help.

[image]

build.gradle (Project:BackboneExampleApp-master)-->

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I also come with the same problem in my application. I have Done **invalidate caches/restart** then the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as yours. Fortunately, I managed to solve it. You need to go to *File >> Settings >> Build, Execution, Deployment >> Build Tools >> Gradle*. You need to change the **Gradle Home**. Mine was "C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/**gradle-2.08**" and it said the path is invalid. So, just recheck your path in your file explorer and change it. I changed mine to "C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/**gradle-2.10**".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately I already tried that. I even downloaded my original gradle 2.4 (which is what I was using before the Android Studio 2.0 installer deleted that directory) and pointed Gradle Home towards that. I also tried gradle 2.12 with no luck. It seems it keeps trying to get to the internet, which it never will be able to do.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I was trying to build one of the media samples. I tried to use gradle 2.0.0 as you suggested but it didn't work. Got me on the right track though. gradle 2.1.0, along with deactivating offline mode got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a connection issue, that I have checked my connection is working in the same second I have enabled and disabled offline Gradle, then Android Studio download the needed files

NB: My Connection was disconnecting and reconnecting many times, so i figured out that this error was caused by the connection specially it was not the same time it takes when trying to sync my Gradle

Answer (score 1):

For those have issues with error message: Learn to configure HTTP settings, below is the solution that worked for me. Am using Android studio 2.3.3:

Go to http://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html
Step 1: Follow the instructions on: Set up Android studio proxy.
  Step 2:  Follow the instructions on : Android plugin for gradle HTTP proxy setting. You will see proxy settings under : # project wide gradle settings, copy the code there and paste it into the empty space in gradle properties file which is under the build gradle in Android studio. Make sure you are connected to internet while on this process.   Wait until the the error disappears.

Step 3: you may see another message pop up stating: some folders may have been missing syn now. Just click on syn now.

I hope this help, thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

I was fallen the same trouble, you mentioned. But I solved it myself. I connected my pc to the internet and rebulit the project using PROJECT>>REBUILT PROJECT.

Then some downloads could be seen below with the name of jcenter.......

THEN THE PROBLEM SOLVED...
Gradle build became successful..

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Make sure that you have made an entry in path in environment variable for gradle

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\bin
```

After disable offline mode and setting the path in environment variables, the issue was fixed and Gradle was build cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are multiple reasons for this issue. I fixed it by changing the "Gradle version" and "Android plugin version".

It might be helpful to someone. Go to File->Project Structure. Select Project and update your gradle and android plugin versions.

Answer (score 0):

I also came with the same problem in my application..The application Gradle version is 2.3.3 .I just update the Gradle to 3.0.1 .and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was different from all answers; gradle distribution url was wrong..
It might be the problem that distributionUrl can be wrong in gradle-wrapper.properties file.