# gradle sync error android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, proxy

I was trying to create some android sample app using android studio and I came across a gradle sync error.

It says unknown host for [jcenter.bintray.com](http://jcenter.bintray.com) and configure proxy.

But when I try to access it using browser url is accessible. I also tried to check connection in android studio > setting > system settings > http proxy > check connection.

It shows connection successful. So the error occurs only when it builds. what could be the reason?

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
}
}

allprojects {
}
```

Comment: Try setting proxy if you are behind the firewall.

Comment: so it should show some error when I try to access in above two cases right?

Comment: While building what error you are getting?

Comment: Unknown host 'jcenter.bintray.com'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.

Comment: Error it self saying to set the proxy. because Android Studio is not able to get through the firewall.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle is failing on syncing my project in the new Android Studio 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502419/gradle-is-failing-on-syncing-my-project-in-the-new-android-studio-2-0)

Comment: @javedsalat I tried to check url accessible via ide and it shows connection successful. That's why am curios about the issue.

Comment: Firewall maybe?

Comment: No need copy and paste, just read [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41554085/errorunknown-host-jcenter-bintray-com)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the android studio could not able to fetch the dependencies from the repository.

Try  updating `android studio to newer version`, along with `deactivating offline mode` got it to work.

Comment: my Android studio version is 2.2 preview 7.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' from build.gradle file, If you are not using unit test.

If you need test case, Set up proxy settings(file->settings->appearance & behaviour ->system settings->http proxy ) , if you are behind proxy.

and add below repository in build.gradle,

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
}
```

Comment: Can you post gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

If it is internet access issue than please check and configure proxy url in the android studio preferences and set Manual proxy url with port.