# Error:Unknown host 'jcenter.bintray.com'.

Tags: android

Error:Unknown host 'This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
[Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy)

Comment: Do you or your company use any type of proxy? This error is caused by Android Studio not being able to access remote dependency repos.

My company uses a proxy and I had to configure the proxy settings in Android Studio before it could pull from jcenter.

Comment: thanku .yes i used the proxy but i cant update android studio using proxy

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Go to File > Project Structure and then:

- Select project in the left-hand menu
- change `jcenter` to `jcenter()` in the Android plugin Repository and Default Library Repository

Comment: For me, this alone didn't work. It did work when after doing this, I changed the full url into 'jcenter' again. Like magic.

Comment: The steps: go to File->Project Structure and select 'Project' on the left pane, you'll see these options on the right

Comment: I wish that someone covers cases when the Internet is temporary unavailable, but all required resources already checked in.

Answer (score 24):

Just **clean** and **Rebuild** the project.
This worked for me

Comment: Sweet answer! 

Comment: What if there is no clean option?

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error and solved the problem using following instruction.

Go to your project level gradle build script add maven { url"https://jitpack.io"} into allprojects.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I shut down my proxy, but it doesn't work.

Then I just try again and again, and add the code below in **build.gradle**

```
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
```

Comment: Is this an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I don't know how I got this error, I completed my project and when I came back from a short break, I saw this error and I don't know how did I run into it.

But after searching an answer over stack overflow, I didn't get one

So just tried to launch another already completed project and it was also giving the same error

Then **I just switch my internet connection from my wifi router to my mobile hotspot and try again** and *it worked*

If you didn't find any answer yet just give this one a try, might this one solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {url"https://jitpack.io"}

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this works for me, when there's a sudden gradle syncing problem which should work fine (or previously worked fine).

**Build with local gradle distribution**

Download a gradle release archive from [here](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/) to path **android-studio/gradle/** folder, and extract it.

In Android Studio: **File > Settings > Build, Execution > Gradle**.

Select 'Use local gradle distribution' under 'Project-level settings'.

In 'Grade home', browse to the path of the downloaded gradle and select it.

OK > Sync project.

P.S. if local gradle is already selected, try reverse i.e. default wrapper.

Comment: after doing above still getting same error, also tried changing `classpath` to `4.1` and `4.1.0` as I updated to gradle `4.1`

Answer (score 0):

Update latest version of dependencies work for me in project level build.gradle!!!

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha05'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
It happens when you are normally offline.
Just turn on your internet connection and retry building the app again.
Otherwise,  you can use an offline or local gradle

Answer (score -2):

This is how i fixed it.

- Disable your system Wifi
- Wait for 10 seconds
- Enable Wifi
- Sync Gradle
- Clean Project
- Build