# Error:Unknown host 'jcenter.bintray.com: Name or service not known'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio-2.3

After updating android studio to 2.3.3 am facing this error. Where I am not getting any display on xml layout. Also it asks me to enable gradle offline mode. But after enabling it it again ask me to enable gradle online mode.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? It sounds like Android Studio is unable to connect to the Internet, so you probably need to correct the networking settings in Android Studio and/or in Gradle.

Comment: I'm getting `Unknown host 'akamai.bintray.com: Name or service not known'.` Maybe Bintray is simply bogus.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Unknown host 'jcenter.bintray.com'.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41554085/errorunknown-host-jcenter-bintray-com)

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I got this problem because my network was temporarily not available...

As the error message indicated, "Unknown host" usually means the hostname cannot be resolved, so just double check if your computer has no access to the Internet, if you have a typo in the hostname, if you have a working DNS configuration, or if you are behind some proxy which does not work well... though all these may sound irrelevant to the Android project itself.

Answer (score -1):

Check your internet buddy, it is due to connectivity issues