# Why this resolves the Gradle Issue in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Often I find that when I import projects from Sample or othersources putting

url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" inside the jcenter() {} my gradle erros like

```
Error:Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.2/gradle-2.1.2.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required
<a href="toggle.offline.mode">Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project</a>
```

gets resolved?
By default there is nothing inside it.
What is happening here and why the error is getting resolved?

I am using Android Studio 2.2

Comment: may be this will help you-http://stackoverflow.com/a/36506257/6291914

Answer (score 1):

Looks like, It is the issue of Gradle version

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
}
```

So, I replaced 2.1.0 with 2.2.0 and the project built just fine.