# Gradle sync errors for a new project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have just installed Android Studio and I am getting these errors while syncing Gradle:

```
Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:design:26.1.0.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1. 

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12. 

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle is failing on syncing my project in the new Android Studio 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502419/gradle-is-failing-on-syncing-my-project-in-the-new-android-studio-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

Add Maven to your project root `gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
         google()
         jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: you can just add `google()` instead of `maven` block. And I'd move it to 1st position too

Answer (score 0):

Add Inside App gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    } }
```

Comment: `maven { url "https://jitpack.io"` is only required when you're using libraries, which are hosted in jitpack.io