# How to solve this error in android studio 2.2.3

Tags: android

> Error:Unknown host 'jcenter.bintray.com'.

You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
[Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle is failing on syncing my project in the new Android Studio 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502419/gradle-is-failing-on-syncing-my-project-in-the-new-android-studio-2-0)

Comment: Go to File>Settings>HTTP Proxy, check "Manual proxy configuration" and set your proxy or check "No proxy"

Answer (score 0):

Your firewall should allow Android Studio, Gradle Dependency end points. Since it can't reach the url & download the dependencies giving the error Unknown Host.

Hope this will help.