# Weird errors after updating to Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

So I saw a new update for Android Studio and I updated.

Although I keep getting errors that are more related to server problems than anything else. But this doesn't relate to my app.

One my apps has this error `Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/sun/xml/bind/mvn/jaxb-parent/2.2.11/jaxb-parent-2.2.11.pom'. Received status code 504 from server: Gateway Time-out
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project`

I tried the offline part but it didn't work.

And another one has this problem

```
    Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.jar'. Received status code 504 from server: Gateway Time-out
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

I would appreciate any help as I am kind of last thanks

//////////

**EDIT**
Apparently it was a problem on the gradle, although here it is

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.reecreate.woderator2"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
      //  resConfigs "auto"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.27.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.charbgr:authmanager:1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.warkiz.widget:indicatorseekbar:1.2.9'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Although now I have this error when I run my app (or try to) "09:54 Error running 'app': Unknown error"

Comment: please post your project build.gradle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle is failing on syncing my project in the new Android Studio 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502419/gradle-is-failing-on-syncing-my-project-in-the-new-android-studio-2-0)

Comment: hello, yes I think it was, I will show you my gradle. Also now I have an error which I will show you on EDIT

Comment: any ideas guys?

Comment: yeah ... Did you tried to turn and off an on again(AS)? it helped me

Comment: Just updated and have the exact same issue.

Comment: i am also facing same thing after 3.1 update

Comment: mean while you can use gradle version 3.0.1

Comment: Some extra news: OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space, this, or GC overhead limit. Happens only on new Android Studio 3.1. JavaMaxHealSize is already set to 4g
Just don't update yet

Comment: Please see this response [Unknown error in Android studio 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49521030/1971757) Regards!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue after updating to 3.1.
But it seems a temporary problem as I try to go to the 502 URL with my browser and I can load it.
After trying to sync again my project, the 502 URL is a new one.
Maybe too many people are updating, causing load problems.

**EDIT**: three hours later, it is all fine for me. Without rolling back anything. Temporary problem confirmed :)

Comment: This is the likely reason. That's why it works with the older gradle plugin (all the dependencies are in the cache) and starts working if you succeed once.

Comment: As I was guessing. Everything works fine again, without touching anything.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem, build fails to download random (every time different) dependency. Downgraded gradle plugin to 3.0.1 and it's working, seems like a bug on their side.

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be in new gradle tools 3.1.0 that you can apply when updating.

Roll it back to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'` in your build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem, it is a temporary problem, no need to worry about it. You need to do one thing: just rebuild or clear or invalid caches continuously. That's it.