# Error running 'app': Unknown error in Android studio 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

I have updated my android studio to new stable **version 3.1**.
After build project not able to run.

Let me know if anyone have face same issue or find any solution.

[image: My event log show this error]

Comment: What happens if you do a manual build via `gradlew clean app:build` in the terminal?

Comment: Let me try it, but i have clean build 2 times and gradlew build it taking around 20 minutes.

Comment: if gradle build taking too much time. try updating gradle version.

Comment: As an alternative, you could try deleting and re-adding your run configurations. Haven't come across this issue, but that's helped me in the past when a project has refused to run for an unclear reason.

Comment: Its already on latest version.

Comment: Ok will check it as per your suggestion. thanks

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49508278/3806413

Comment: Yes its working thanks @0xalihn

Comment: Build>Clean Project, Build>Rebuild Project solved same problem for me

Comment: @0xalihn answer worked for me.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just go to "**Run/edit configurations...**/" and scroll down to bottom of the window and here you see an option "**Before launch...**" 
First, remove whatever already inside the little window and then click on (**+**) icon and select **"Gradle-aware Make**" and then type "**assembleDebug**" and select the first option or that you need. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Both this and @erine [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49521024/1009782) where helpful. I deleted both build folders and it worked.

Comment: This works for me. But could you please add a comment or link on what it actually does? To me it sounds like it is changing the may how it is built/assembled.

Comment: both of the answer is not working for me. My classes are showing cannot resolve but the apk build is working. Android studio 3.1 and its killing me

Answer (score 16):

Try deleting both your build folders in your project manually and rebuild. This usually happens when you update gradle version, in my experience.

Comment: This, along with the selected answer, solved it for me.

Answer (score 9):

The solution that worked for me was a combination of other answers here.

I had upgraded to the most recent stable version of Android Studio at the time, 3.1. Along with that, Android Studio prompted a dialog asking me if I wanted to upgrade my Gradle from 3.x to 4.4, and I accepted as well.

After that I got the error of this question, and then I did this:

1. Open menu `Run` -> `Edit configurations...`
2. In the `Before launch:` section, select any options you have listed (each option has the Android symbol), and remove them with the `-` symbol
3. Add the option `Gradle-aware Make`, with the value `assembleDebug`
4. Clean and rebuild your whole project

Comment: for me, `assembleDebug` value does not required. just leave empty.

Answer (score 2):

just clean and rebuild your project

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I change in build.gradle 'compile' with 'implementation', then clean and rebuild the project. Now it starts with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run "Build-> Clean Project" normally will fix this problem.

Comment: Normal clean build can not fix the problem if Gradle-aware Make changes are not done.