# enable gradle 'offline mode' and sync project is poping in android studio even though i unchecked the offline mode

Tags: android, android-studio

im trying to run my project in android studio , it was saying enable gradle   'offline mode' and sync project, But i already unchecked the offline mode

Comment: Check your internet connection...

Comment: Check your proxy connection..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle is failing on syncing my project in the new Android Studio 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502419/gradle-is-failing-on-syncing-my-project-in-the-new-android-studio-2-0)

Comment: What error you getting beside "enable offline mode"?

Comment: Thanks all for the repy i understood proxy is the issue but even though i disabled proxy from setting tab and changed to no proxy ... still its saying unknow host proxy

Comment: Did you try the answers from question [Gradle is failing on syncing my project in the new Android Studio 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502419/gradle-is-failing-on-syncing-my-project-in-the-new-android-studio-2-0)?. It looks like the problem is similar to what you are having.

Answer (score 0):

During your gradle build, some automatic downloads may be required. It will be better to connect to the internet and build again so that no internal errors happen. Otherwise, you can check the offline mode and sync the project.

Comment: Thanks all for the repy i understood proxy is the issue but even though i disabled proxy from setting tab and changed to no proxy ... still its saying unknow host proxy

Answer (score 0):

Gradle can't connect to the defined repository to check and update some of the library you use so it suggests that you go in offline mode. However if you never built the project before there is a good chance that there is no cached version of required library either, so:

1. Check if your internet connection is OK
2. Check if you added any
   library recently that may caused the problem - try commenting them
   before syncing again
3. Check if you changed or added any repository inside your project gradle files

Comment: Thanks all for the repy i understood proxy is the issue but even though i disabled proxy from setting tab and changed to no proxy ... still its saying unknow host proxy

Comment: Remove the proxy setting from your gradle.properties file located in Project directory too. The setting tab only set the proxy used in android studio itself.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your comment, please go to gradle.properties file (project root directory) and find lines like below:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy.company.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=443
systemProp.http.proxyUser=username
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.http.auth.ntlm.domain=domain
```

**Detele** these lines and click `File - Sync project with gradle files`. If you find these lines in your module `build.gradle` file or other place, also delete them.

Answer (score 0):

1.Open Your project.
 2.Go to the Left side of the Gradle button.
 
3. [image]

4. Click button above image shows.
5. If this type of view you are not in offline mode.
6. Go to Build and rebuild the project.

All above is working for me.