# Sync fail in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Unknown host 'maven.parse.com'. 
You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.

- Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
- Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle

getting this error and not build project

also not visible Run icon. Please check this image

[image: Please check this image]

Comment: Its showing you this error you does not have internet connection to download dependencies you have added in you module gradle file. So enable offline mode or internet connection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle is failing on syncing my project in the new Android Studio 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502419/gradle-is-failing-on-syncing-my-project-in-the-new-android-studio-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File->Settings`
Search For `Gradle` in the search box and then uncheck the `Offline work` checkbox and then try to sync project.

[image: Gradle Offline]